# Get last document from userchat for each user - mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**User Schema**

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  phoneno: { type: String },
  email: { type: String },
  password: { type: String },
  profilePic: { type: String },
  socketId: { type: String },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

**UserChat Schema**

```
const userChatSchema = new Schema({
  message: { type: String, required: true },
  sender: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: "User" },
  receiver: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: "User" },
  time: { type: Date, required: true },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("UserChat", userChatSchema);
```

I need a query to fetch only last userchat of currently logged in user with all other users i.e. a chat where currently logged in user can be *sender or receiver* and each of all other users can also be *sender or receiver*  and that chat must be **latest** chat between logged in user and other user.

[User and UserChat collections](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0oVHyweQ7NZ)

e.g. if currently logged in user is `ObjectId("6039c2513b3fd51f3595d82f")`,
then query must give following output:

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("6039c2393b3fd51f3595d82e"),
    name: "userONE",
    phoneno: "123456",
    latestMsg: {
      _id: ObjectId("6039c2df3b3fd51f3595d833"),
      message: "from userONE to userTWO 1",
      receiver: ObjectId("6039c2513b3fd51f3595d82f"), // logged in user
      sender: ObjectId("6039c2393b3fd51f3595d82e"),
      time: ISODate("2021-02-27T03:56:15.122Z"),
    },
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("6039c25c3b3fd51f3595d830"),
    name: "userTHREE",
    phoneno: "12345678",
    latestMsg: {
      _id: ObjectId("6039c60ea8061225286e57e4"),
      message: "from userTWO to userTHREE 4",
      receiver: ObjectId("6039c25c3b3fd51f3595d830"),
      sender: ObjectId("6039c2513b3fd51f3595d82f"), // logged in user
      time: ISODate("2021-02-27T04:09:50.579Z"),
    },
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("6039c2673b3fd51f3595d831"),
    name: "userFOUR",
    phoneno: "123456789",
    latestMsg: {
      _id: ObjectId("6039c5f2a8061225286e57e2"),
      message: "from userFOUR to userTWO 3",
      receiver: ObjectId("6039c2513b3fd51f3595d82f"), // logged in user
      sender: ObjectId("6039c2673b3fd51f3595d831"),
      time: ISODate("2021-02-27T04:09:22.283Z"),
    },
  },
]
```

Comment: would be great if you can share sample data, the code you are trying and the expected result :) [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/) would be a convenient tool to do so.

Comment: for **User** collection [link]https://mongoplayground.net/p/vHjuYNJf4Oi

Comment: for **UserChat** collection [link]https://mongoplayground.net/p/OvFz4Ao4wZe

Comment: You can define multiple collections in Mongo playground: `db={
"User": [
{},...
], 
"UserChat ": [
{},...
]
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scenario of the answer:

1. Total three users.
2. Prakash1, Prakash2 have chatted with Dheemanth twice.
3. Dheemanth has responded to Prakash1 so Dheemanth's response is the last message shown.
4. Dheemanth has not responded to Prakash2 so Prakash2's last message is shown.

Query:

```js
db.users.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            _id: ObjectId("6039437ce0c7d52970d3f9f3") // Loged in user _id
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "chats",
            let: { user_id: "$_id" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $or: [
                                { $eq: ["$receiver", "$$user_id"] },
                                { $eq: ["$sender", "$$user_id"] }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $sort: { time: -1 }
                },
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: {
                            $concat: [
                                { $toString: { $min: ["$sender", "$receiver"] } },
                                { $toString: { $max: ["$sender", "$receiver"] } }
                            ]
                        },
                        sender: { $first: "$sender" },
                        receiver: { $first: "$receiver" },
                        message: { $first: "$message" },
                        time: { $first: "$time" }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "latestMsg"
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$latestMsg" }
]);
```

Output: for Dheemanth

```js
/* 1 createdAt:2/27/2021, 12:22:44 AM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6039437ce0c7d52970d3f9f3"),
    "name" : "Dheemanth",
    "latestMsg" : {
        "_id" : "6039437ce0c7d52970d3f9f36039437ce0c7d52970d3f9f5",
        "sender" : ObjectId("6039437ce0c7d52970d3f9f5"),
        "receiver" : ObjectId("6039437ce0c7d52970d3f9f3"),
        "message" : "Can u help me?",
        "time" : ISODate("2021-02-27T00:38:00.000+05:30")
    }
},

/* 2 createdAt:2/27/2021, 12:22:44 AM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6039437ce0c7d52970d3f9f3"),
    "name" : "Dheemanth",
    "latestMsg" : {
        "_id" : "6039437ce0c7d52970d3f9f36039437ce0c7d52970d3f9f6",
        "sender" : ObjectId("6039437ce0c7d52970d3f9f3"),
        "receiver" : ObjectId("6039437ce0c7d52970d3f9f6"),
        "message" : "Ok paste your query.",
        "time" : ISODate("2021-02-27T00:41:00.000+05:30")
    }
}
```

Output: for Prakash1

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6039437ce0c7d52970d3f9f6"),
    "name" : "Prakash1",
    "latestMsg" : {
        "_id" : "6039437ce0c7d52970d3f9f36039437ce0c7d52970d3f9f6",
        "sender" : ObjectId("6039437ce0c7d52970d3f9f3"),
        "receiver" : ObjectId("6039437ce0c7d52970d3f9f6"),
        "message" : "Ok paste your query.",
        "time" : ISODate("2021-02-27T00:41:00.000+05:30")
    }
}
```

Test data:

Users

```js
/* 1 createdAt:2/27/2021, 12:22:44 AM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6039437ce0c7d52970d3f9f6"),
    "name" : "Prakash1"
},

/* 2 createdAt:2/27/2021, 12:22:44 AM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6039437ce0c7d52970d3f9f5"),
    "name" : "Prakash2"
},

/* 3 createdAt:2/27/2021, 12:22:44 AM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6039437ce0c7d52970d3f9f3"),
    "name" : "Dheemanth"
}
```

Chats

```js
/* 1 createdAt:2/27/2021, 1:21:05 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6039f9e9e0c7d52970d3fa43"),
    "sender" : ObjectId("6039437ce0c7d52970d3f9f6"),
    "receiver" : ObjectId("6039437ce0c7d52970d3f9f3"),
    "message" : "Hi im am Prakash1",
    "time" : ISODate("2021-02-27T00:39:00.000+05:30")
},

/* 2 createdAt:2/27/2021, 1:21:05 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6039f9e9e0c7d52970d3fa44"),
    "sender" : ObjectId("6039437ce0c7d52970d3f9f6"),
    "receiver" : ObjectId("6039437ce0c7d52970d3f9f3"),
    "message" : "Need some help!!!",
    "time" : ISODate("2021-02-27T00:40:00.000+05:30")
},

/* 3 createdAt:2/27/2021, 1:21:05 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6039f9e9e0c7d52970d3fa45"),
    "sender" : ObjectId("6039437ce0c7d52970d3f9f3"),
    "receiver" : ObjectId("6039437ce0c7d52970d3f9f6"),
    "message" : "Ok paste your query.",
    "time" : ISODate("2021-02-27T00:41:00.000+05:30")
},

/* 4 createdAt:2/27/2021, 1:21:05 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6039f9e9e0c7d52970d3fa46"),
    "sender" : ObjectId("6039437ce0c7d52970d3f9f5"),
    "receiver" : ObjectId("6039437ce0c7d52970d3f9f3"),
    "message" : "Hi im am Prakash2",
    "time" : ISODate("2021-02-27T00:37:00.000+05:30")
},

/* 5 createdAt:2/27/2021, 1:21:05 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6039f9e9e0c7d52970d3fa47"),
    "sender" : ObjectId("6039437ce0c7d52970d3f9f5"),
    "receiver" : ObjectId("6039437ce0c7d52970d3f9f3"),
    "message" : "Can u help me?",
    "time" : ISODate("2021-02-27T00:38:00.000+05:30")
}
```

Comment: Your query returns latest chats that are received by current logged in user, what I want is a query that returns a latest chat between currently logged in user and other user such that the receiver of that chat can be currently logged in user or the other user, and this applies for all other users too.

Comment: Ok check the modified query and result. This must work!

Comment: Further if u need sorting like: The latest msg among last messages from every user, u can add another stage `{ $sort: { "latestMsg.time": -1 } }` at the end after `$unwind`.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. How can we populate the **sender** and **receiver** field in output?

Comment: Perform two separate `$lookup`s to `users` collection inside main outer `$lookup`.